# Alertdialog isShowing always returns false

Tags: android

```
    public class myActivity extends Activity
    {
            private static AlertDialog somedialog = null;

            protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
            {
              somedialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(ctx).create();
              innerclass = new innerclass();
              innerclass.start();
            }
            private class innerClass extends Thread
            {
               if (!somedialog.isShowing())
               {
                             runOnUiThread(new Runnable()
                             {
                                  somedialog.setMessage("test");
                                  somedialog.show();
                             }
                }
            }


    }
```

I have this code where I have a dialog which needs to show only if the dialog is not already there. The dialog is only shown by the innerClass. There is no other method which invokes this somedialog object.

I expect the dialog to appear for the first time and to reappear only if the previous dialog has been closed, however I find there are multiple dialogs stacked on.

For some reason the isShowing method is returning false even if the dialog is open.

Any ideas as to why this is happening?

However when this code is executed somedialog.isShowing() is always returning false and hence I get multiple dialogs on top of each other.

Comment: Is this the actual code of your activity class?

Comment: that is just a mockup code, but rest of the contents of my activty will be too cluttering to post here, I only instantiate the dialog once as above and its accessed only in the innerclass thread where its populated and shown

Answer (score 2):

You are creating a new instance of AlertDialog every time

```
 new AlertDialog.Builder(ctx).create();
```

and checking `isShowing()` before it showing. As a result it always return false.

Comment: I only create it once in onCreate

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for everyone who tried to help me out in this query. It finally turns out to be silly coding error @ midnight. I have multiple runOnUiThreads inside the innerclass thread, in one of them the alert object was being re-created.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible there are some issues introduced by your multi-threading, and the value of `isShowing()` being cached as it is read between threads. I can't see the purpose of `innerClass` from your example, and would simply remove it. This would also be akin to:

```
private class innerClass extends Thread {
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        if(!someDialog.isShowing()) {
            somedialog.setMessage("test");
            somedialog.show();
        }
    }
}
```

Also, you shouldn't keep a `static` reference to your `AlertDialog` - there's no need, it wont play nicely with the lifecycle of your `Activity`, and it's a memory leak waiting to happen.

Comment: The innerclass thread has to monitor some NON UI events and update dataobjects as well as the UI. I will try to create a separate project with a simple dialog activity and a thread to isolate the problem.